Partition by in mysql
I have a table "countries" which contains population data of countries. There are 5 distinct "region_id"s - 10,20,30,40,50
I have this query:
select name, region_id,
sum(population) over (partition by region_id) as tot_pop
from countries

When I run the query, the rows are returned in the ascending order of "region_id" - in the order 10, 20, 30, 40, 50. Is this beacuse I said "partition by region_id"? So does partition by column_name sort the column_name or am I getting the result this way because the rows themselves were inserted in ascending order of region_id into the table?
Say I have this table:



Pop
Region_id




1000
10


2000
20


9000
10


3000
10


2000
20


4000
20



So when partition by region_id is executed I am assuming that the records are taken in the following order:



Pop
Region_id




1000
10


9000
10


3000
10


2000
20


2000
20


4000
20



Am I right in assuming so?

If a query has no ORDER BY clause, its result are arbitrarily ordered. If the result is ordered in some way, it just happens to be so and may change any time you run the query again. Add an ORDER BY clause, if you want the result to be in a particular order. Does this answer your question?

This query calculates the total population for each region_id and returns the results. The PARTITION BY region_id groups the rows by region_id for the purpose of the SUM(population) calculation, but it does not sort the rows.
To explicitly control the order of the results, you should use the ORDER BY clause in your query.
SELECT name, region_id,
       SUM(population) OVER (PARTITION BY region_id) AS tot_pop
FROM countries
ORDER BY region_id;

When you add ORDER BY region_id, it explicitly sorts the result set by region_id.
